# oncomplete function is not working

Tags: service-cloud-console, console, oncomplete

I am refreshing the primary tab after clicking on the update button.i am using the oncomplete function. on the command button oncomplete action is not working.

i have tried in the following way:

```
 <apex:commandButton action="{!calculateMilestone}" title="Submit" value="Update" 
     reRender="id1" status="loadStatus"  rendered="{!controls}" 
     oncomplete="testRefreshPrimaryTabById()"/>
```

Comment: Can you please provide more code samples if the question above didn't help?

Answer (score 0):

Dileep - a couple of things to check:

Does your action (calculateMilestone) return a null page reference - if not, make sure it does. A rerender on a non null return of PageReference does not exactly behave as intended. Also make sure to have the browser console/dev tools etc open so you can see whether the issue is to do with invoking the testRefreshPrimaryTabById() function on the browser.